# Show fieldset depending on input of previous fieldset

Tags: jquery, html, fieldset

im fairly new to programming, so i hope my questions doesnt bother anyone:

I have a multistep form written in html, css and jQuery which shows one slide, after another. 
I want it to the following: It should not show just the next fieldset, but a fieldset, based on the input of the previous fieldset.

This is one of my fieldsets:

```html
 <fieldset id="Programming_Language">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Programming Language</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">What did you use?</h3>
    <select>
  <option value="a">Java</option>
  <option value="b">JavaScript</option>
</select>
  </br>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
```

This is the jQuery code, which just shows the next fieldset:

```js
$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
```

The desired behavior is, to display the fieldset with id=Java_Framework if the person picks Java and to display the fieldset with the id=JavaScript_Framework if the person picks JavaScript

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override the value of next_fs based on which language is selected. Assuming you have 2 fieldsets already present after the current fieldset replace the

```
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
```

with

```
//do this only for this fieldset
if(current_fs.attr('id')=='Programming_Language'){ 
   var lang = current_fs.find('select').val(); //get the selected language

   if(lang=='a'){
      next_fs = $(this).parent().next('#Java_Framework');   
   }
   else if(lang=='b'){
      next_fs = $(this).parent().next('#JavaScript_Framework');
   }
   else{
      next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
   }
}
else{
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - I replaced the code. Now, the fieldset "Programming_Language" just disappears and the new ones dont show up.

Comment: is it selecting the lang value correctly? test with console.log(lang); and if it does then what is the value of next_fs? it appears that next_fs is null hence nothing shows up next.

Comment: I checked it with the console. The result is: console.log(lang);
VM29:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: lang is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: I have updated the code to check for nulls. If after applied the modification you still get the same original behavior (like prior to making any changes) this means that you are not getting value of lang from select. Look into jquery on how to read value of a select.